# XCODE 4.5 - Expected Identifier... (UIWebView) - iPhone

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

**View controller h:**

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController

{
IBOutlet UIWebView *WebView1;
IBOutlet UIWebView *WebView2;
IBOutlet UIWebView *WebView3;
IBOutlet UIWebView *WebView4;
IBOutlet UIWebView *WebView5;
}

@end
```

**view controller m:**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface UIViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

NSURL *myURL1 = [NSURL URLWithString:[@"http:://www.youtube.com"]];
                NSURLRequest *MyRequest1 = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:myURL1];
                [WebView1 loadRequest:MyRequest1];

NSURL *myURL2 = [NSURL URLWithString:[@"http:://www.gmail.com"]];
                NSURLRequest *MyRequest2 = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:myURL2];
                [WebView2 loadRequest:MyRequest2];

NSURL *myURL3 = [NSURL URLWithString:[@"http:://www.soundcloud.com"]];
                NSURLRequest *MyRequest3 = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:myURL3];
                [WebView3 loadRequest:MyRequest3];

NSURL *myURL4 = [NSURL URLWithString:[@"http:://www.socialblade.com"]];
                NSURLRequest *MyRequest4 = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:myURL4];
                [WebView4 loadRequest:MyRequest4];

NSURL *myURL5 = [NSURL URLWithString:[@"http:://www.fullscreen.net"]];
                NSURLRequest *MyRequest5 = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:myURL5];
                [WebView5 loadRequest:MyRequest5];
}

@end
```

**Decription:**

The error is on each of the links "]". What am I dong wrong?
And I can't link/connect my outlets to the UIWebView's set up in tabs.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple. You do not need the []'s around each string. Change it's URL to the following:

SURL *myURL4 = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http:://www.socialblade.com";
                NSURLRequest *MyRequest4 = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:myURL4];
                [WebView4 loadRequest:MyRequest4];

That should solve it. If not, let me know.

### Edit

Also, you are declaring your properties incorrectly, which is causing your to not connect them. You should declare your webView's like this:

View controller h:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController


@property (assign) IBOutlet UIWebView *WebView1;
@property (assign) IBOutlet UIWebView *WebView2;
@property (assign) IBOutlet UIWebView *WebView3;
@property (assign) IBOutlet UIWebView *WebView4;
@property (assign) IBOutlet UIWebView *WebView5;


@end
```

Then you must synthesize them in your .m
view controller m:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface UIViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize WebView1;
@synthesize WebView2;
@synthesize WebView3;
@synthesize WebView4;
@synthesize WebView5;
```

After they are synthesized, you can call them as you have done. :)

Comment: that did it, though how can i link outlet's to webviews? I can drag an outlet out though it doesnt let me add it to the webview :/

Comment: Still cant link them to the separate tabs UIWebViews with that code.

Comment: Have you linked your view controller with this custom controller. In the IB, you need to find the tab that allows you to type in a Custom Class. Use ViewController. Also, make sure you are dragging from your controller to the webview, not the webview to the controller.